# SQL insert into multiple columns doesnt work?

Tags: sql, mariadb

yesterday I had the problem that I couldn't insert multiple values into my columns. It turned out that the problem was that my key was missing an auto_increment. I've been trying to to the same thing(inserting multiple values into columns) now on another table but for some reason it doesn't work for me. I made the same changes as I did to the other table which works now. I can't imagine what I could've missed, can anyone help me with this?
Here the table specification and error:
[image: error]

Comment: What have you tried? To me it looks like you are inserting the same key, i.e. a value that already exists in your table as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When you mark the PK as auto-increment you do not have to insert values to that entry anymore as it will be incremented automatically, therefore will not trigger any duplicate problems due to being different to the previous PK entries. I suggest you to add only the values of the non PK columns.

INSERT INTO tbllaptops(L_ProzTyp, L_Akku, L_MietgebuehrProTag) -> VALUES ('i56600', '8000mha', '8.5')